# How to print name of month as string?

Tags: biblatex

I know I can print the current month (or day) as an integer with `month` (or `day`).

How can I make use of the localisation information to print it as a string?

```
03 -> March
```

EDIT: Added a MWE

.bib file:

```
@ONLINE{IPAustraliaStandardPatentApplication,
    author = {{IP Australia}},
    title = {Standard patent application process | IP Australia},
    year = 2013,   
    note = {http://www.ipaustralia.gov.au/get-the-right-ip/patents/patent-application-process/standard-patent-application-process/}, 
    urldate = {2013-05-21},
}
```

macro:

```
% URL Dates
\renewbibmacro*{urldate}{%
    \printtext[parens]{%
      \printfield{urlday}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \printfield{urlmonth}%
      \setunit*{\addspace}%
      \printfield{urlyear}%
    }%
    \newunit%
}
```

I want `urlmonth` to be printed as, eg, `May`.

Comment: You've added the `biblatex` tag, but it sounds like you're asking for a solution that allows you to print the name of the current month anywhere in the document, right?

Comment: If you are talking about the bibliography, then this is automatic: as long as the month is an integer, `biblatex` automatically localises the month based on the babel settings or `language` option.

Comment: Jake - actually, I'm only interested in the bibliography.  @PLK - it doesn't appear to be doing so.  I'm getting the actual integer printed out in my bibliography when I do `\printfield{month}`

Comment: For future reference, it would be helpful if you can construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that community members can copy-and-paste to start working on a solution.

Comment: @Werner - added MWE (I didn't think it would be necessary for this simple of a solution)

Comment: In that case we will need a MWE as this looks more like a biblatex localisation issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is very simple: the formatting of the `urldate` in the bibliography is controlled by the `urldate` option of the `biblatex` package. Thus

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,urldate=comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Test 1 \cite{IPAustraliaStandardPatentApplication}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

will produce the desired output (converting `urlmonth` to a word), assuming your bibliography is in `test.bib`. For more options consult section page 60 of section 3.1.2.1 of the `biblatex` manual.

---

**Update:** To change the exact format of the date you have to modify the definitions of the `mkbibdatelong` macro. This is defined in the language specific files, so in your case `english.lbx` (assuming you write in english).

To avoid modifying those you can do the redefining in your preamble. Below I include code which should print the date in the format "21 May, 2013".
*I have not tested all the corner cases, such as day but no month, etc.*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,urldate=comp]{biblatex}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{% y/m/d 
    % taken from english.lbx
        \iffieldundef{#3} %day
          {}
          {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}\space}%
          \iffieldundef{#2} %month
          {}
          {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
           \iffieldundef{#3}
             {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}
         {,\nobreakspace}}%
             %\iffieldundef{#1}{}{,\space}
        \stripzeros{\thefield{#1}} %year
    }%
}


\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Test 1 \cite{IPAustraliaStandardPatentApplication}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's got me almost there.  One thing left - the format (when using `\printurldate`) is currently, eg, `August 15, 2011`.  How can I swap this so that it becomes `15 August, 2011`?

Comment: @sapi see the updated answer, I hope that is what you were looking for.